# org-mode and following links to `#+name: target` things

Tags: org-mode

I have the following in my org-mode buffer:

```
#+name: my-element-name
```

and then I made a link to that:

```
and here is a link to [[my-element-name]].
```

According to the [org-mode manual on internal links](https://orgmode.org/org.html#Internal-Links), that ought to work, but when I try to following the link with `C-c C-o`, I get an error: `Wrong type argument: stringp, nil`.

I'm using org 9.4 from ELPA; I've used edebug on some of the functions and it seems that something isn't working deep inside `org-link-search` but I couldn't figure out where. I see some regexp matching in that function...this seems like something that ought to work.

Using NAME instead of "name" didn't make a difference.

Is this expected to work? It seems like it.

(More generally, what's the difference between "dedicated targets" -- the ones `<<like-this>>` -- versus "named elements" with `#+NAME: some-name-here`?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `name` keyword is an "affiliated" keyword: it is affiliated to the following element, so it cannot exist on its own.

Try:

```
#+name: my-table
| a | b |

#+name: my-code-block
#+begin_src emacs-lisp
(message "foo")
#+end_src

[[my-table]]
[[my-code-block]]
```

If you do `M-x org-lint` in your buffer, you'll see something like this:

```
     6 low   Orphaned affiliated keyword: "NAME"
    17 high  Unknown fuzzy location "my-element-name"
```

Comment: Thanks! However, when I run `org-lint`, I get: `17 files scanned, 16 files contains IDs, and 908 IDs found. Not enough arguments for format string`.

Comment: No idea why you get that - can you `M-x toggle-debug-on-error RET` and try the `org-lint` again? If you get a decent backtrace, maybe you can open another question on that or send a bug report with `M-x org-submit-bug-report RET`, including the backtrace in the bug report.